# Issues loading page with CocoaHTTPServer using a WiFi module

Tags: iphone, wifi, hardware

I have a RN-171 WiFLy module (I'm very new to working with hardware, btw) and I need it to talk to an iPhone over WiFi.

To achieve that, I've chosen to host a web server on the iPhone using CocoaHTTPServer, set the RN-171 in Adhoc mode, join the network via the iPhone and then send requests to the iPhone server via the device.

The module works correctly when I try to load a page on my Mac (running on Apache). The device prints out *OPEN*, shows the returned HTML and then prints out *CLOSE*.

With the iPhone application, however, it simply hangs at *OPEN* for a while until it times out and then shows *CLOSE*. I've put a breakpoint in the application and can indeed see that it is hitting the iPhone server but for some reason the server is responding correctly.

I couldn't figure out the issue by stepping through the application but I'm guessing that the request isn't being closed or something.

```
set dns name www.rovingnetworks.com
set ip host 0
set ip remote 80
set ip proto 18
set com remote GET$/server.php?value=
set sys auto 10
set option format 1
set uart mode 2
save
reboot
```

The above are the commands I'm entering into the device to try and get it to connect taken from [manual](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://www.rovingnetworks.com/resources/download/93/WiFly_User_Manual&ei=Yg9NUL2wJoWyiQe_oIHADw&usg=AFQjCNGr3LfUqNpTcac5PnDZpbFj15L6kQ&sig2=7iO25ASUOyo7m8RH0pzQ8g). In my case, I'm setting the dns name to the iPhone IP and the remote string to the GET$/index.html?value= however I'm not having any luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was using Picocom to talk to the device. I set the options to convert linefeeds and carriage returns to CRLF and it worked correctly.